# Unable to move from activity to fragment

Tags: java, kotlin

How to move from activity to fragment on button click?

```
private fun onClickListener() {
            profileImageView.setOnClickListener {
                val i = Intent(this, ProfileFragment::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
            }
}
```

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can either move from activity to activity or fragment to fragment.
In the first case you can use the code you have implemented with

```
private fun onClickListener() {
        profileImageView.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(this, SecondActivityWhatever::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }
```

}

otherwise you need to implement Navigation Component in order to move from fragment to fragment.

(Another option in your specific case would be using a Custom Fragment Dialog to show the profile)